What video settings for analog FPV headset that help to identify obstacles?
I mean settings like contrast, color, brightness, and sharpness on FPV goggles. So that it's easier to view objects along my path to avoid collision.

From my experience, these settings dont make much of a difference or give a significant advandage, so just go with what looks best to you.

There's no single answer for this. The reason these things are adjustable is that the optimum settings will depend on your camera and the lighting conditions on the day.
